Surface integral of the second type
Can anyone help me please :(
Calculate the surface integral of the $2$nd type:
$$
\iint_S \dfrac{x^2\,dy\,dz + y^2\,dz\,dx + z^2\,dx\,dy}{x^3+y^3+z^3}
$$
where $S$ is the outer side of a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$.

sure. Have you done a surface integral before? if you have, what part of the process worked there that doesn't work here?

I have done some exercises but I have never seen such a difficult one like this. I've tried using the polar coordinate but the integrand is so complicated

Have you tried to use the spherical coordinates to calculate the integral?

if so, then I have to use the divergence theorem but I think it would be more complicated :(

@ghostio  Divergence theorem is probably the way to go.

@Abezhiko does divergence theorem apply? there is a singularity at the origin, so $d\omega$ isn't defined there.

The integrand reduces nicely (albeit with a lot of trigonometric manipulation) if you parameterize $S$ with the right set of spherical coordinates.

@user170231 the usual spherical change of coordinates doesn't work as nicely? To be clear, I haven't done the work.

@JackozeeHakkiuz  The singularity will be "compensated" by the Jacobian of spherical coordinates. Indeed, the integrand behaves like $\frac{1}{r}$, while the Jacobian is proportional to $r^2$.

The vector field
$$
\boldsymbol{F}=\frac1{x^3+y^3+z^3}\pmatrix{x^2\\y^2\\z^2}
$$
is parallel to the unit outward normal at the sphere
$$
\boldsymbol{n}=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}
$$
and
$$
\boldsymbol{F}\cdot\boldsymbol{n}=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}=\frac1r\,.
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
&\int_S\frac{x^2\,dy\wedge dz+y^2\,dz\wedge dx+z^2\,dx\wedge dy}{x^3+y^3+z^3}
&=\int_S\boldsymbol{F}\cdot\boldsymbol{n}\,dS=\frac1r (4\pi r^2)=4\pi r\,.
\end{align}
Alternatively, you can go the hard way and take spherical polar coordinates. This leads to
\begin{align*}
&\int_S\frac{x^2}{x^3+y^3+z^3}\,dy\wedge dz=r\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\cos^3\varphi\sin^4\theta}{\cos^3\varphi\sin^3\theta+\sin^3\varphi\sin^3\theta+\cos^3\theta}\,d\theta\,d\varphi\,,\\[2mm]
&\int_S\frac{y^2}{x^3+y^3+z^3}\,dz\wedge dx=r\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin^3\varphi\sin^4\theta}{\cos^3\varphi\sin^3\theta+\sin^3\varphi\sin^3\theta+\cos^3\theta}\,d\theta\,d\varphi\,,\\[2mm]
&\int_S\frac{z^2}{x^3+y^3+z^3}\,dx\wedge dy=r\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\cos^3\theta\sin\theta}{\cos^3\varphi\sin^3\theta+\sin^3\varphi\sin^3\theta+\cos^3\theta}\,d\theta\,d\varphi\,.
\end{align*}
The sum of these integrals is
$$
r\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\varphi=r4\pi\,.
$$

But sir why that is the cross product while $F.dS$ is the scalar product

That is because Elie Cartan got the very good idea to invent differential forms when he was drinking a lot of absinthe one day.

@ghostio Joking aside. The relationship between the differential form integral and the $dS$-integral is something fundamental that you should learn and remember. This is not the place to repeat it. Studying the literature and practicing examples is the way to go.

The wedge product of differential forms is not cross product of vectors, although in $\Bbb R^3$ they are related. Your $dx,dy$ notation for a surface integral omits the wedge, although, as @Kurt wrote, it should be there for rigor. If you want to see a more detailed, careful treatment of differential forms and surface integrals, you might look at my YouTube lectures, linked in my profile.
